# Disable language switching by mouse overlay on macOS

Tags: macos

I'm using MacBook (macOS Monterey) and change language by the fn button. Quite often I can't switch the language because the cursor is on the language popup. Is there any way to turn this off?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the questions! When I switch language on the keyboard and the language popup pops up, if the cursor was located in the popup place I can't switch language, because the cursor selects it.

Comment: I'm using macOS Monterey

Comment: How exactly are you switching the language? I'm just hitting the keyboard shortcut (⌘+Space for me), and the popup doesn't even appear. I need to hold the key combination for a second or so to even see the popup.

Comment: I'm using MacBook and change language by the fn button. https://store.storeimages.cdn-apple.com/4982/as-images.apple.com/is/mbp16-spacegray-gallery1-202110?wid=4000&hei=3072&fmt=jpeg&qlt=90&.v=1632799176000

Comment: Try using Control Space instead.  Also you can use Caps Lock between British and Ukrainian, if you check the box for that in Keyboard > Input Source Preferences.

Comment: Thank you for the advice! Yes, it works, but I'd rather use the fn( button, I'm already used to switching languages that way